# Why does this work in Python2.7 but not in Python3.5?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, lxml

I have the following code that validates an XML document against an XSD:

```
import lxml
import lxml.etree

xsd_definition = lxml.etree.XML('''\
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                elementFormDefault="qualified">
        <xs:element name="test" type="testType"/>
        <xs:complexType name="testType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="testElement" type="testElementType"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexType name="testElementType">
            <xs:attribute name="intAttr" type="xs:positiveInteger" use="required"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
''')
xsd = lxml.etree.XMLSchema(xsd_definition)
parser = lxml.etree.XMLParser(schema=xsd)

test_xml = '''\
    <test>
        <testElement intAttr="10"/>
    </test>
'''
lxml.etree.fromstring(test_xml, parser)
```

This works in Python2.7, but it does not work in Python3.5.  In Python3.5, I get the following exception:

```
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Element 'testElement', attribute 'intAttr': '' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'xs:positiveInteger'.
```

It would seem the parser isn't reading the value of "10" for the "intAttr" attribute of the "testElement" element.  Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: when I copy paste abovecode in my interpeter, it woorks under both 2.7 and 3.5. I can reproduce the error by replacing intAttr="10" with intAttr="". so with an empty strin as the exeption also indicates that an empty string is not a valid integer. is above your actual code or is it just a representation?

Comment: Really?  Now that's super interesting.  It's the actual code.  I think this indicates a problem with my actual Python 3.5 installation rather than a problem of something changing between Python3.5 and Python2.7 (either in the language itself or with the lxml library).  I just copy pasted the code directly off of this page and into my python3.5 interpreter just to see what would happen, and I got the same error.  I am using the Python3.5 packages from Debian "testing" so maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: my exact python version is 3.5.2 (and2.7.12 ) running on ubuntu. If you need to compare with your version. On 2.7 I needed to install lxml as external dependency.

Comment: I solved it.  I used pip3 to install lxml.  I then uninstalled it (using "pip3 uninstall"), and then installed Debian's python3-lxml package and now it works.  Debian's python3-lxml package is version 3.7 while the lxml that got installed using pip3 was 3.8.  Your comment pointed me in the right direction that would've otherwise taken me forever to head towards.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Maybe you should go ahead and answer your own question. I did not mean to do it in the comment. :)

Comment: just for your information, I tried to reproduce your issue in a virtualenv with python 3.5 and lxml 3.8 but was unable to. May have been a one-off. would be interesting to know if the issue comes back for you after upgrading lxml.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem was with the version of lxml I was using.  The version of lxml I was using with python 2.7 was 3.7 while the version I was using with python 3.5 was 3.8.  The reason for this discrepancy is because I used Debian's lxml package to install lxml for python 2.7 while I used pip to install lxml for python 3.5.  Once I dropped down to 3.7 for python 3.5, the problem went away.